# Does this sum have any meaning?

Tags: summation

In class today I was looking at the sum $1 +\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}...$ and with a bit of fiddling, managed to come up with the following: $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \left(\sum_{m=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n^m} \right) = 1$$
I managed to show this in 2 different ways: [Method 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0XI4.jpg) and [Method 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZGo1.jpg), mostly the same method, yes.

But I was wondering if this is at all meaningful, has it been used in anything at all? Does it mean anything apart from it's something that's pretty cool?

Comment: Are you asking for its meaning in physical sense, like how to interpret the result geometrically?

Comment: I'm interested in anything regarding it, I'm just generally interested in any interpretation since I happened to stumble across it.

Comment: That result is correct: it is just using standard results in geometric series and telescopic ones. What I don't see clear is what has the harmonic series to do with all this...

Comment: @DonAntonio The only thing it has to do with the harmonic series is how I came up with it, since I noticed when I expanded the harmonic series using the infinite sum for fractions such as 1 = 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8... 1/2 = 1/3 + 1/9 + 1/27 ... and 1/3 = 1/4 + 1/16 + 1/64 ... I could expand the series into a new series that had itself less 1 which when cancelled gave me the series above i.e when you take all the expansions and remove the first terms you get what must equal 1. This is what I posted above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is one of the several identities involving the [Riemann Zeta Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html)
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(\zeta(n)-1)=1.$$
Here there is another one
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^n\cdot (\zeta(n)-1)=\frac{1}{2}.$$
You can try to prove it by considering
$$\sum_{n=2,4,6,\dots}(\zeta(n)-1)=\frac{3}{4}$$
and 
$$\sum_{n=3,5,7\dots}(\zeta(n)-1)=\frac{1}{4}.$$

Comment: Oh, huh, that's cool, thanks a lot. I think I've only heard of the Riemann Zeta function in numberphile videos and in an old New Zealand Scholarship Calculus paper I did, I'll look into it

Comment: @Simon Goodwin You're welcome. You can try to prove also the identity with $(-1)^n$ by following the hint above.